# how to empty an array when the value of the array changes?

Tags: perl

lets assume i have an array @atom. i am pushing three elements `$a`, `$b`, `$c` (residue name, chain and residue number respectively fetched from pdb file) into that array. for instance, `$b` has values ***AAAAAAAAA***, ***BBBBBBB***, ***CCCCCCC***. how to empty the array every time when `$b` changes?

The array is as follows,

```
push(@atom,"$a $b $c");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question/the problem. Please try to create a [mcve]. What do you mean with "$b changes"?

Comment: How do you notice that `$b` changes? /// You are not pushing three elements to your array. You are pushing _one string_ (which constist of `$a`, a blank, `$b`, a blank, `$c`) to your array. To push three elements use `push(@atom, $a, $b, $c);` (without quotes).

Comment: `@atom = qw(aa bb cc); @atom = "" if($atom[1]!~m/dd/i);`

Comment: You are pushing only one element to your array. You are creating a new string, and you are pushing that. At that point, `$b` is not there as an entity any more. Only the value of `$b` is part of that string, which is the single (or last) element of `@atom`. There is no way to make `@atom` know that `$b` changed to clear it.

Comment: @ssr1012 you are overwriting `@atom` with a one-element list that contains the empty string. That's hardly _clearing_ it.

Comment: @simbabque: _how to empty the array every time when $b changes?_ yeah exactly what OP asks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Perhaps reconsider your data model?

Comment: @ssr1012 an empty array would be an array that holds an empty list, which is `()`, and has _no elements_. That's a big difference to a list with one element which is an empty string.

Comment: @ssr1012: That's terrible advice. Please remove it. `@atom = ""` **does not** empty an array.

Comment: @priya Go with hashes.

Comment: @ssr1012: Also a regex check seems bizarre here. It's quite possible to change `$atom[1]` to a different value that would still match the regex. (And did you get confused between `bb` and `dd` while writing your answer?)

Comment: If `$atom[1]` stored `bb` executed the script then changes happened eg `dd`

Comment: @ssr1012: You're talking nonsense. You store 'bb' in `$atom[1]`. Then your code says "overwrite `@atom` with an empty string if `$atom[1]` doesn't match `/dd/`". So if nothing has changed, you will overwrite `@atom`. That's not what the OP asked for at all. Please just delete your ridiculous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using an array when you're only storing a single value in it. You think you are storing three values, but you are putting those into a single string before storing them in the array.

To store three values in your array, you might use code like this:

```
my @atom = ($residue_name, $chain, $residue_number);
```

(Notice that I have also changed your variable names. `$a`, `$b` and `$c` are terrible names for variables and `$a` and `$b` are special variables for Perl and should not be used in random code.)

I don't really know what you are doing here, but it seems to me that it might make more sense to store this data in a hash.

```
my %atom = (
    residue_name   => $residue_name,
    chain          => $chain,
    residue_number => $residue_number,
);
```

Of course, that's only a guess as I don't know what you need to do with your data - but an important part of programming is to get your data structures right.

But let's assume for now that you're still using your original array and you want to a) see if the `$chain` variable has changed its value and b) empty the array at that point. You would need to write code something like this:

```
my @atom = ($residue_name, $chain, $residue_number);
# Store the current value of $chain
my $original_chain = $chain;
```

Then, later on, you need to check the value has changed and take appropriate action.

```
if ($chain ne $original_chain) {
  @atom = ();
}
```

Of course, this is all just the sketchiest of suggestions. I have no idea how your code is structured.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a $b $c are read in a loop and pushed in an array

```
while (...) {
    # read $a $b $c

    if ($b ne $last_b) {
        @atom = ()  # atom is affected to a new empty array
    }

    push @atom, ...

    $last_b=$b
}
```